# Freezing the state of an ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Was wondering if there is a way to "freeze" a running ec2 server. This means existing processes are not killed but saved, they are then resumed when the instance is resumed.

Virtualbox from Oracle allows this, hoping amazon does the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible in EC2.

As an aside, Virtualbox is an Oracle product, not VMware. VMware's main virtualization products are ESXi, VMware Workstation, and VMware fusion.

Comment: Thanks, updated. Any advice on how to speed up the start and stop of medium windows instances?

Comment: That's a separate question. Please post it as such, making sure you provide what you've done to research this, an where you think the slowness is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2018 you can hibernate and save memory to EBS, at least on Amazon Linux.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/amazon-ec2-now-lets-you-pause-and-resume-your-workloads/